# Algebra equation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a+3b=7$ and $c=3$. Then value of $a+3(b+c)$ is

A) $10$

B) $16$

C) $21$

D) $30$

Answer is B, but how?

Comment: Use $$a+3(b+c)=a+3b+3c$$ and since you have a value for both $a+3b$ and $c$ you can just evaluate.

Comment: Do you mean $$a+3b=7$$ and $$c=3$$?

Comment: Add $ a+3b =7 $ to three times $c$ value $ = 9$

Answer (score 2):

We are told that $\color{blue}{a+3b} = 7$ and that $\color{red}{c}=3$

We are asked to find $a+3(b+c)$

$$\begin{array}{rll}a+3(b+c) &=a+(3b+3c)&\text{distributive property}\\
&=(a+3b)+3c&\text{associative property}\\
&=(\color{blue}{a+3b})+3\color{red}{c}&\text{recognition}\\
&=7 + 3\cdot 3&\text{replacement}\\
&=7+9=16&\text{arithmetic simplification}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:  Distribute first then substitute what you recognize:

$a+3(b+c) =$

$a + 3b + 3c = $

$(a + 3b) + 3(c)= $ (and we know $c=3$ and $a+3b = 7$ so..)

$7 + 3*3 = 7 + 9 = 16$.

Method 2: Substitute what we know first.

$a+3(b+c) =$

$a+3(b+3) =$

$a+3b + 9 =$

$(a+3b) +9  =$

$7+9 = 16$.

Method 3: (perhaps overkill) Reduce the unknowns:

$a +3b = 7$ so $a = 7 - 3b$.

Replace $a$ with $7-3b$ and $c$ with 3$.

$a + 3(b+c) = $

$(7-3b) + 3(b + 3) =$

$(7-3b) + 3b + 9 =$

$7 +(-3b+3b) + 9=$

$7+0 + 9 = 16$.

3$\frac 12$. (the wrong choice but all ways will work;)

$a +3b = 7$ so $3b = 7-a$ and $b = \frac {7-a}3$.

Replace every $b$ with $\frac {7-a}3$ and every $c$ with $3$.

$a + 3(b + c) =$

$a + 3(\frac {7-a}3 + 3)=$

$a + (7-a) + 9 =$

$(a-a) + 7 + 9 = 0 + 7+9 = 16$.

Answer (score 0):

For questions like these where you cannot solve for each value to then find the solution, you are supposed to substitute some form of the given equation in for the variable. You are given a number for c so substitute that into the equation $ a+3(b+c) $ first. 
$$ a+3(b+3) $$
We cant to find a way to substitute $ a+3b $ into the equation since we know the value of $ a+3b $ is 7. First, let's try expanding the formula to see if the equation appears:
$$ a+3b+9 $$
We see $a+3b$ in the first part of the equation, so we can substitute 7 in for $a+3b$:
$$ 7+9 $$
Now, we can solve!
$$ 16 $$
For problems like these, find a way to rearrange the final equation in a way that will allow you to substitute the given equations into it.